# Prove or disprove: a Continuous Function Attains its Maximum with Given Limit Conditions

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and

$
\lim_{{m \to \infty}} \sup_{{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x \rVert \geq m}} f(x) = 0.
$

Then $f$ attains its maximum value.

My attempt:

To prove that $f$ attains its maximum, we will make use of the extreme value theorem.

Given that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we know that $f(x)$ is bounded below by zero. We need to show that $f$ is also bounded above.

Let's assume that $f$ is not bounded above. This implies that for any positive integer $n$, there exists a vector $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x_n) > n$.

Consider the sequence $ \left\{x_n\right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space, we can extract a subsequence $\left\{x_{n_k}\right\}$ that converges to a point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\left|x\right| \geq m$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and for sufficiently large $m$, we have $\left|x_{n_k}\right| \geq m$.

Taking the limit as $k$ approaches infinity, we have $\left|x_0\right| \geq m$ for all $m$. This implies that $x_0$ is unbounded, which contradicts the fact that $x_0$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Therefore, our assumption that $f$ is not bounded above is false. Hence, $f$ must be bounded above by some constant $M$.

Now, we can apply the extreme value theorem, which states that if $f$ is a continuous function defined on a closed and bounded interval, then $f$ attains its maximum and minimum on that interval.

In our case, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded, so by the extreme value theorem, $f$ attains its maximum. This completes the proof.

Comment: But... $\mathbb R^n$ is unbounded. Several of your arguments above proceed as if it was bounded. It is not. For one thing, a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ need not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: that's correct but I don't have a better idea till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$, the statement is obviously true.

Suppose now that $f(x_0)=a>0$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$. This implies that there is $m\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sup_{||x||\ge m}f(x)<a$. It follows that $f(x)<a$ for $||x||\ge m$. This also lets us conclude that $||x_0||<m$ as $f(x_0)=a\not< a$.

Now, on the bounded set $||x||\le m$, the function $f$ attains its maximum $f(x_1)=b$. As $x_0$ is in that same set, it follows that $b=f(x_1)\ge f(x_0)=a$. Thus, $b\ge f(x)$ for $||x||\le m$ and $b\ge a>f(x)$ for $||x||\ge m$. In other words, $f(x)\le b=f(x_1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$, so $f$ reaches its maximum on the entire $\mathbb R^n$.